# ruby program basic design explanation

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to rewrite the following code with the code below, but I am stuck.

```
def ask question
good_answer = false
while (not good_answer)
    puts question
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase

    if (reply == 'yes' or reply =='no')
        good_answer = true
        if reply == 'yes'
            answer = true
        else
            answer = false
        end
    else
        puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no"'
    end
end
answer
end
```

Replacement code:

```
def ask question
    puts question
    reply = gets.chomp
    if (reply == 'yes' or reply == 'no')
        puts reply.capitalize
    else
        puts 'Please enter "yes" or "no"'
        #jump the code to like 2 ( but how?)- use while reply != empty & comment the below lines
        puts question
        reply = gets.chomp
    end
end
```

I want to jump to the main part of program is there any goto, jump or can I call method inside that method?

Comment: Ruby is normally indented with two spaces, not four.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def ask question  
puts question  
reply = gets.chomp.downcase  
if (reply == 'yes' or reply == 'no')  
    puts reply.capitalize  
else  
    puts 'Please enter "yes" or "no"'  
    ask question # this does the looping of loop
end
end
```

Thanks, and sorry I didn't copy it well from my clipboard last time.

Comment: Making this recursive is completely unnecessary and you have also changed the semantics of the method.

Comment: Ed.S, this thing works this is what I wanted. But I'm not following your remark about his answer.

Comment: @Clone: Ok, that's fine, but you're using recursion just for the hell of it here.  You risk blowing your stack for no good reason (not likely here, but still possible) when a loop is simple and more clear.

Comment: This assumes that Ruby has proper tail calls, which unfortunately is false.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, then how to solve if I have some thing to deal like above

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ruby supports recursion and tail calls just fine. However, it does not
optimize tail calls (in terms of stack usage).

Comment: @Dave: I don't understand your comment. I never claimed that Ruby doesn't support recursion. Actually, I didn't say *anything* about recursion. Recursion isn't even mentioned anywhere in my comment. I also never claimed that Ruby doesn't support tail calls. So, what's your point?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I couldnt quite get your previous comment. Can you explain what you intend to say in _This assumes that Ruby has proper tail calls, which unfortunately is false_ or was there something wrong that I made in code?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to jump to the main part of program is there any goto, jump or can I call method inside that method?

Yes, it is called a loop, i.e., what you are using in your original code.  Why in the world would you want to replace a loop with a goto?  Makes no sense.

It can however be simplified.  I don't like the checking against 'yes' or 'no', but I also don't have time to restructure your program.

```
def ask question
  while true
    puts(question)
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase
    if reply == 'yes' || reply == 'no'
      return reply == 'yes'
    else
      puts('Please answer "yes" or "no"')
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to recheck the answer. is there any way like I call some `var.ask` something like that.

Comment: @Clone: I still have no idea what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there was a `goto` statement you shouldn't be using it. Not only is it bad form, but it causes all kinds of headaches for maintainers since your program ends up being hard to follow.

A better approach is to define proper structures for your questions and valid answers, then iterate over those simply, collecting the results into a structure you can use later:

```
# Auto-flush output buffer
STDOUT.sync = true

questions = [
  [ 'Is this a good question?', 'yes', 'no' ],
  [ 'Is the sky blue?', 'yes', 'no' ],
  [ 'Do hamsters fly?', 'no', 'yes' ]
]

answers_given = [ ]

questions.each do |question, *answers|
  print question + ' '

  while (true)
    answer = gets

    answer.chomp!

    if (answers.include?(answer))
      puts "Thanks!"

      answers_given << (answer == answers.first)

      break
    end

    puts "You must answer one of #{answers.join(', ')}!"
    print question + ' '
  end
end

questions.each_with_index do |(question, *answers), i|
  puts "#{question} #{answers_given[i]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something liek this:

```
def ask_question  
  puts('Please answer "yes" or "no"') until (reply = gets.chomp.downcase) =~ /^(yes|no)$/

  return reply == 'yes'
end
```